# Possible bug Integrate[(1-x^(-1/5))/(1-x),{x,0,1}]=0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Summary**

It seems that `Integrate[]` cannot handle complicated branch cuts of the integrand properly.

**The problem**

This integral

```
i5 = Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]

(* Out[1682]= 0 *)
```

returns a wrong result.

The numerical values is

```
i5n = NIntegrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]

(* Out[1683]= -0.387793 *)
```

The same result holds for higher values:

```
Table[Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/n))/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}], {n, 2, 10}]

(* Out[1706]= {-Log[4], 1/6 (Sqrt[3] \[Pi] - 9 Log[3]), 
 1/2 (\[Pi] - 2 Log[8]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

**Analysis**

1) The antiderivative shows no sign of irregularity like jumps

```
ia = Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x), x]

(* Out[15]= -5 RootSum[
  1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + #1^4 &, (Log[x^(1/5) - #1] #1^3)/(
   1 + 2 #1 + 3 #1^2 + 4 #1^3) &] *)
```

[image]

The difference of the values at the borders is ok.

```
(ia /. x -> 1) - (ia /. x -> 0);
% // N

(* Out[1722]= -0.387793 + 0. I *)
```

2) The integral with a variable upper limit shows several branch cuts

```
iy[y_] = Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x), {x, 0, y}, 
  Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1]

(* 
Out[2]= -(-1)^(1/5) Log[1 + (-y)^(1/5)] + 
 Log[1 - y^(1/5)] + (-1)^(2/5) Log[1 - (-1)^(2/5) y^(1/5)] - (-1)^(3/5)
   Log[1 + (-1)^(3/5) y^(1/5)] + (-1)^(4/5) Log[1 - (-1)^(4/5) y^(1/5)] - 
 Log[1 - y]
*)
```

which leads to difficulties with the values at `y=1`

```
% /. y -> 1

(* Out[3]= Indeterminate *)

iy[1]

(* Out[4]= Indeterminate *)
```

But it works with the limit:

```
Limit[iy[y], y -> 1]

(* Out[12]= -Log[5] - (-1)^(1/5) Log[1 + (-1)^(1/5)] + (-1)^(2/5)
   Log[1 - (-1)^(2/5)] - (-1)^(3/5) Log[1 + (-1)^(3/5)] + (-1)^(4/5)
   Log[1 - (-1)^(4/5)] *)

% // N

(* Out[14]= -0.387793 - 1.11022*10^-16 I *)
```

It also works numerically close to 1:

```
iy[1. - 10^-6]

(* Out[24]= -0.387793 - 3.33067*10^-16 I *)
```

Comment: Also, `Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True] // Simplify` works.

Comment: Isn't this function non-integrable on [0,1] since it has an undefined value at x=1?

Comment: Specifying the path of integration as {x, 0, 1/2, 1} also works ( on the cloud).

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ Thanks, I had the same idea but the result was a root sum, so I was not happy with it.

Comment: @ Gandalfmeansme No it is perfectly integrable. Close to $x=1$ the integrand goes like $-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3 (x-1)}{25}$ (Use Series[] to see this).

Comment: @  Michael E2  Interesting idea. How did you come up with it? It works also for other intermeadiate points. But I think to really find a closed solution one has to work accoding to pargraph 2 of my analysis.

Comment: @ Michael E2 Following my own plan outlined just now, I have simplified the solution to $\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sqrt{1+\frac{2 \sqrt{5}}{5}}-\frac{5 \log (5)}{4}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \operatorname{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{5}\right)$ Nice exercise in replacements.

Comment: I have observed that specifying the path in the complex plane by giving one or more way points between the endpoints seems to help `Integrate` resolve the correct branch(es).  I have also observed that it does not always work.  So if the integral is meant to be completely real, I thought inserting a real waypoint between 0 and 1 might help. Alternatively, it splits the branch point from the singular point (`PrincipalValue` probably does this, too). That might also be the reason.

Comment: @ Michael E2 Here's an example. Purely real: Integrate[Log[1 - x], {x, 0, 2}] (* Out -2 + I \[Pi] *), go through the upper half plane: Integrate[Log[1 - x], {x, 0, 1 + I, 2}] (* Out  -2 - I \[Pi]*),  go through the lower halfplane: Integrate[Log[1 - x], {x, 0, 1 - I, 2}] (* Out  -2+ I \[Pi]*). Hence Mathematica chooses to go through the lower half plane if it does the real integral.

Comment: I filed a bug report for this.

Comment: Mathematica 5.2 produces the correct result for this definite integral, directly and immediately. But Mathematica 8.0.4 already does not, it gives 0. Such a progress.

Comment: @ Daniel Lichtblau Thank you. I wasn't sure.

Comment: @ innaiz Thank you very much for reminding me of my beloved version 5.2. :-)

Comment: Cross ref: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220493/why-is-product1-1-k5-k-1-infinity-equal-to-zero-in-12-1

Comment: The bug seems to have been fixed in MMA 12.2 but it returned an extremely lengthy answer and took a little while... One can fullsimplify the lengthy answer and get `1/2 Sqrt[1 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi] - 1/2 Sqrt[5] ArcCoth[Sqrt[5]] - (
 5 Log[5])/4` though

Answer (score 8):

You can do

```
Integrate[(1 - x^-y)/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]
(* HarmonicNumber[-y], Re[y] < 1*)]
```

and then

```
(HarmonicNumber[-y] /. y -> 1/5) // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* 1/2 Sqrt[1 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi] - 
 1/2 Sqrt[5] ArcCoth[Sqrt[5]] - (5 Log[5])/4*)
```

Comment: @ Andreas Welcome in the forum, and congratulation for the brilliant entry (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Since it was too long for a **comment**, I transcribe everything here together:

```
f1[x_] := Sqrt[(5 + Sqrt[5])/2] ArcTan[(1 - Sqrt[5] + 4 x^(1/5))/Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]]
f2[x_] := Sqrt[(5 - Sqrt[5])/2] ArcTan[(1 + Sqrt[5] + 4 x^(1/5))/Sqrt[2 (5 - Sqrt[5])]]
f3[x_] := -(5 - Sqrt[5])/4 Log[2 + (1 - Sqrt[5]) x^(1/5) + 2 x^(2/5)]
f4[x_] := -(5 + Sqrt[5])/4 Log[2 + (1 + Sqrt[5]) x^(1/5) + 2 x^(2/5)]
f[x_] := f1[x] + f2[x] + f3[x] + f4[x]

int1 = Integrate[(1 - Surd[x, -5])/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify;
int2 = Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x) // ComplexExpand, {x, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify;

D[f[x], x] == (1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x) // FullSimplify
int1 == int2 == f[1] - f[0] // FullSimplify
```

> True
>
> True

Comment: So what is the conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting how we can simplify the expression obtained by Mathematica with the method 2) of my analysis:

```
iy1 = -Log[5] - (-1)^(1/5) Log[1 + (-1)^(1/5)] + (-1)^(2/5)
   Log[1 - (-1)^(2/5)] - (-1)^(3/5) Log[1 + (-1)^(3/5)] + (-1)^(4/5)
   Log[1 - (-1)^(4/5)]
```

The basic action is a replacement exemplified here

```
Log[1 + (-1)^(1/5)] /. Log[a_] -> (Log[Abs[a]] + I Arg[a]) // FullSimplify

(* = 1/2 ((I \[Pi])/5 + Log[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) *)
```

As an intermediate step we transform the sum into a list so that the replacement can act on each term separately

```
List @@ iy1

(* = {-Log[5], -(-1)^(1/5) Log[1 + (-1)^(1/5)], (-1)^(2/5)
   Log[1 - (-1)^(2/5)], -(-1)^(3/5) Log[1 + (-1)^(3/5)], (-1)^(4/5)
   Log[1 - (-1)^(4/5)]} *)

% /. Log[a_] -> (Log[Abs[a]] + I Arg[a]) // FullSimplify

(* = {-Log[5], 
 1/2 (-1)^(1/5) (-((I \[Pi])/5) + Log[2/(5 + Sqrt[5])]), 
 1/2 (-1)^(2/5) (-((3 I \[Pi])/5) + Log[1/2 (5 - Sqrt[5])]), 
 1/10 (-1)^(1/10) (3 \[Pi] + 5 I Log[1/10 (5 + Sqrt[5])]), 
 1/10 (-1)^(3/10) (\[Pi] + 5 I Log[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])])} *)
```

Now we return to the sum adding the terms

```
Plus @@ %;
```

Then follows the main simplifying step with

```
ExpToTrig[%] // Simplify

(* = 1/40 (2 (Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 
      3 Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) \[Pi] + 5 Log[4] - 45 Log[5] + 
   5 Sqrt[5] Log[10] + Sqrt[5] Log[32] - 5 Log[5 - Sqrt[5]] + 
   5 Sqrt[5] Log[5 - Sqrt[5]] - 5 Log[5 + Sqrt[5]] - 
   15 Sqrt[5] Log[5 + Sqrt[5]]) *)
```

And other simplifying steps admittedly without a stringent logical seqence but the result of trial and error (as is often the case with Simplify[]-ing)

```
PowerExpand[%] (* useful for expanding Log[ A B ] *)
FullSimplify[%]

(* = 
1/2 Sqrt[1 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi] - (5 Log[5])/4 + 
 1/8 Sqrt[5] Log[1/2 (7 - 3 Sqrt[5])] *)
```

Which is the final result.

Remark: compare my question in the Math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555539/prove-int-01-frac1-frac1-sqrt5x1-x-dx-frac-pi2-sqrt1-frac2-sqr