# Why is Product[1 + 1/k^5, {k, 1, Infinity}] equal to zero in 12.1?

Tags: bugs, products, version-12.1

**Bug introduced in 12.1. Fixed in 12.2.**

---

In all versions up to 12.0 it is

```
 Product[1 + 1/k^5, {k, 1, Infinity}]
 (* 1/(Gamma[1 - (-1)^(1/5)] Gamma[1 + (-1)^(2/5)] Gamma[1 - (-1)^(3/5)] Gamma[1 + (-1)^(4/5)]) *)
```

Numerically

```
 (* 2.07422504479637891390708968594384056977125337962227288334734 *)
```

not equal to zero.

But in version 12.1 I get

```
 Product[1 + 1/k^5, {k, 1, Infinity}]
 (* 0 *)
```

What went wrong?

Comment: That's gross. Please contact the support at Wolfram about this. We cannot fix it. (I don't think you did anything wrong. But it is always a good idea to restart the kernel and to try again.)

Comment: Definitely a bug. I reported it.

Comment: The same issue with `Product[1 + 1/k^(2*n+1), {k, 1, Infinity}], n=3,4,...`

Comment: Same bug for Product[1 - 1/k^5, {k, 2, Infinity}]

Comment: Workaround: `Limit[Product[1 + 1/k^5, {k, 1, n}], n -> ∞]` gives the correct answer `1/(Gamma[1-(-1)^(1/5)]*Gamma[1+(-1)^(2/5)]*Gamma[1-(-1)^(3/5)]*Gamma[1+(-1)^(4/5)])`.

Comment: Another workaround: `1/Product[k^5/(k^5 + 1), {k, 1, Infinity}]`

Comment: It reminds me of the bug i5 = Integrate[(1 - x^(-1/5))/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]: (* Out[1682]= 0 *) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215089/possible-bug-integrate1-x-1-5-1-x-x-0-1-0/215197#215197

Comment: OP's issue seems to have been fixed in version 12.1.1. But the integral bug has not.

Comment: Fixed in version 12.2