# Need to verify strange behavior with Product[]

Tags: products

I'm running 12.1.0.0 on MacOS X x86 (64-bit).  The expression

```
Product[1 - 1/n^5, {n, 2, Infinity}]
```

yields `0` as output, which is clearly false.  [Wolfram Alpha gives the correct result.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1-n%5E-5%2C%7Bn%2C2%2CInfinity%7D%5D)  In fact, it appears that

```
Product[1 - 1/n^k, {n, 2, Infinity}]
```

for any odd integer $k \ge 5$ returns `0`.  Replacement of `Infinity` with a large positive integer gives the expected result.  Is anyone else able to replicate this issue?  I have a strong suspicion that this is due to some problem with handling the choice of complex branch.

Comment: I get the same result as W|A gives with 12.1.1. I do not have 12.1.0 installed any longer, so I cannot test that version.

Comment: You can try to convert the product into a sum of logarithms

Comment: Duplication of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220493/why-is-product1-1-k5-k-1-infinity-equal-to-zero-in-12-1

Comment: On 12.0 I obtain the same result as W|A, so this looks like a regression.I suggest that you report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: In v12.1, [`NProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NProduct.html) gives correct numeric results.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer as I cannot comment yet.

> Is anyone else able to replicate this issue?

Yes, I can confirm that Mathematica 12.1.0.0 on Linux and Mac gives the answer 0, same for the odd integers greater than 5.

In Mathematica 11.3.0.0 the code

```
Product[1 - 1/n^5, {n, 2, Infinity}] // InputForm
```

yields

```
1/(Gamma[2 + (-1)^(1/5)]*Gamma[2 - (-1)^(2/5)]*Gamma[2 + (-1)^(3/5)]*Gamma[2 - (-1)^(4/5)])
```

Odd integers bigger than 5 also seem to work.